# Trigger another job from a job, but based on a boolean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Was able to figure out how to trigger another job from my job using `Trigger/call builds on other projects`. This is how I have my setup currently -

Main job Configuration:

- Choice param values: `No`, `Build another job to setup binaries`
- Build -> Trigger/call builds on other projects:

  - Configured the params the job expects

When I select the choice currently when triggering main job, it triggers the other job correctly.

Does anyone if there's a way to simply use a `boolean` param? (instead of the choice param)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for in case someone else trying to figure this out - https://plugins.jenkins.io/conditional-buildstep/